# Fail to connect Oracle db with JNDI lookup in jetty app

Tags: java, oracle11g, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I'm using Jetty ver. 9.4.2.v20170220 with oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource (ver 11.2.0.4) to connect(then insert) Oracle Database 11g Express Edition. I'm confused by problem with setup of lookup for my Datasource. I'm still getting wrong Oracle URL adress. tostring of my connection object look like this: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource@3d10bb5a . I'm sure that drivers were installed properly becouse direct connection like:

```
private static Connection getDBConnection() {

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    try {

        Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        return dbConnection;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return dbConnection;
```

works perfect( I can make insert without any problems). But I don't want to hardcode connection properties, I would like to read them from xml configuration file.

my jetty-env.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN"    "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure id='wac' class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

<New id="DSTest" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg><Ref refid="wac"/></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/DSTest</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
            <Set name="DriverType">thin</Set>
            <Set name="URL">jdbc:oracle:system:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</Set>
            <Set name="User">mylogin</Set>
            <Set name="Password">mypass</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>

</Configure>
```

Fragment of web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>My DataSource Reference</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/DSTest</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

and fragment of servlet code (for connection then insert):

```
private static Connection connTest() throws NamingException, SQLException {

    Context initContext = new InitialContext();
    DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/DSTest");
    System.out.println(dataSource);
    System.out.println(dataSource.toString());
    Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    return connection;
}


@POST
@Path("/testinsert")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response testinsert(SimpleJsonModel simpleJsonModel) {

    String result = "JSON saved test: " + simpleJsonModel;

    try {
        insertRecord(simpleJsonModel.getJsonId(), simpleJsonModel.getNumber());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();
}

private static void insertRecord(String val1, String val2) throws SQLException {

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    String insertTableSQL = "insert into json.johny_table ( jsonId, numberJ) values ('" + val1 + "', '" + val2 + "')";

    try {
        dbConnection = connTest();
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
        System.out.println(insertTableSQL);
        statement.executeUpdate(insertTableSQL);
        System.out.println("inserted");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }
        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

So, question is how to read jndi properties correctly by lookup and how to estabilish connection with it. And any tips how to read strings like url's from jetty-env.xml?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything was fine except one line in jetty-env.xml :

```
<Set name="URL">jdbc:oracle:system:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</Set>
```

schould be:

```
<Set name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</Set>
```

I don't khow why I put word system there.